# SQLiteDatabase not displaying information ImageButton Crashes App

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments, android-sqlite

I'm creating a Calorie App for my class project. I attempted to implement a database to store the information of the calories added by the user which would be displayed in  a listview. The user will input the calories in the add_entry fragment and be displayed on the fragment_home page in the listview.

Problem: I'm not sure if I'm adding the information correctly to the database using the Entry Add Fragment in order to display the info in the listview. this is my first time working with Android Studio/App.

Problem 2:
For Some Reason when I click on imagebutton on my homefragment app crashes and
it doesnt go to the add_entry fragment

logcat:

```
         04-06 00:33:41.213 30567-30567/com.example.treycoco.calorietracker E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                 Process: com.example.treycoco.calorietracker, PID: 30567
                                                                                 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method Click(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton with id 'AddItems'
                                                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod(AppCompatViewInflater.java:325)
                                                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:284)
                                                                                     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5697)
                                                                                     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22526)
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229)
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

FragmentHome.java

```
                  public class FragmentHome extends Fragment implements
         View.OnClickListener  {

        public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";
        public static final String ARG_ID = "_id";
        private TextView label;
        private int sectionNumber = 0;
        private Calendar fragmentDate;
         ListView  listview;
         ImageButton AddEntrybtn;
           CalorieDatabase calorieDB;

            private android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager;
       private FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;

           public FragmentHome() {
            // Required empty public constructor
          }
        @Override
     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

      View myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container,
         false);
      label= (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
        AddEntrybtn = (ImageButton) myView.findViewById(R.id.AddItems);
          return myView;
             }

            @Override
         public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

            Bundle username = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras();



           String username1 = username.getString("Username");

          TextView userMain= (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.User);

        userMain.setText(username1);

        openDataBase();

    }



          private  void openDataBase (){


      calorieDB= new CalorieDatabase(getActivity());
       calorieDB.open();


     }

   private void closeDataBase(){
         calorieDB.close();
       };


       private  void populateLVFromDB(){

    Cursor cursor = calorieDB.getAllRows();




    String[] fromFieldNames = new String[]
            {CalorieDatabase.KEY_NAME, CalorieDatabase.KEY_CalorieValue};
    int[] toViewIDs = new int[]
            {R.id.foodEditText,     R.id.caloriesEditText,           };


                   SimpleCursorAdapter myCursorAdapter =
                   new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                      getActivity(),        
                     R.layout.row_item,
                       cursor,                  
                      fromFieldNames,           
                        toViewIDs                
                      );


         listview = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listView);
          listview.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter);


             }


              @Override
          public void onResume() {
             super.onResume();
         // set label to selected date.  Get date from Bundle.
    int dayOffset = sectionNumber - FragmentHomeDayViewPager.pagerPageToday;
    fragmentDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    fragmentDate.add(Calendar.DATE, dayOffset);
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(appMain.dateFormat);

           String labelText = sdf.format(fragmentDate.getTime());
          switch (dayOffset) {
               case 0:
             labelText += " (Today)";
                 break;
              case 1:
                 labelText += " (Tomorrow)";
                   break;
              case -1:
              labelText += " (Yesterday)";
                 break;
              }
            label.setText(labelText);

   }



           @Override
          public void onDestroy() {
                super.onDestroy();

             }


                @Override
            public void onDetach() {
                super.onDetach();

         startActivity( new Intent(getContext(),MainActivity.class));
          }


         @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
              switch (v.getId()) {
                   case R.id.AddItems:

            AddEntry addEntry    = new AddEntry();

            fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.FragmentHolder,addEntry)

                    .commit();


            break;
             }


         }
        }
```

CalorieDatabase.java

```
                    public class CalorieDatabase {

             private static final String TAG = "DBAdapter";


         public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
             public static final int COL_ROWID = 0;


        public static final String KEY_NAME = "Description";

       public static final String KEY_CalorieValue = "Calories";


           public static final int COL_NAME = 1;
              public static final int COL_CalorieValue= 2;



        public static final String[] ALL_KEYS = new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
          KEY_NAME, KEY_CalorieValue};

        public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "CalorieDb";
      public static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "Calorie_Info";

          public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

           private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_SQL =
              "create table " + DATABASE_TABLE
                + " (" + KEY_ROWID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "


                + KEY_NAME + " text not null, "
                + KEY_CalorieValue + " integer not null, "


                + ");";


         private final Context context;

        private DatabaseHelper myDBHelper;
            private SQLiteDatabase db;



            public CalorieDatabase(Context ctx) {
              this.context = ctx;
               myDBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
              }

           public CalorieDatabase open() {
              db = myDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                return this;
              }


            public void close() {
              myDBHelper.close();
           }


        public long insertRow(String description, int CalorieVal) {


           ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
           initialValues.put(KEY_NAME, description);
           initialValues.put(KEY_CalorieValue, CalorieVal);


          return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
             }


            public boolean deleteRow(long rowId) {
                String where = KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId;
               return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, where, null) != 0;
                  }

                   public void deleteAll() {
                 Cursor c = getAllRows();
                 long rowId = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(KEY_ROWID);
                 if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                     do {
                    deleteRow(c.getLong((int) rowId));
                   } while (c.moveToNext());
             }
               c.close();
               }


              public Cursor getAllRows() {
               String where = null;
                 Cursor c =     db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, ALL_KEYS,
            where, null, null, null, null, null);
               if (c != null) {
                     c.moveToFirst();
                 }
                    return c;
                          }


                 public Cursor getRow(long rowId) {
             String where = KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId;
               Cursor c =   db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, ALL_KEYS,
               where, null, null, null, null, null);
                if (c != null) {
                     c.moveToFirst();
                    }
                   return c;
                    }


              public boolean updateRow(long rowId, String description, int 
          CalorieValue) {
               String where = KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId;


             ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();
            newValues.put(KEY_NAME, description);
                newValues.put(KEY_CalorieValue, CalorieValue);



         return db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, newValues, where, null) != 0;
                  }

           private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
             {
                  DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
                   super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
                    }

                             @Override
                  public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase _db) {
                     _db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_SQL);
                        }

                        @Override
             public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase _db, int oldVersion, int
                     newVersion) {
               Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading application's database from version " +
            oldVersion
                + " to " + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old
                 data!");


                     _db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);


                      onCreate(_db);
                    }
               }
        }
```

AddEntry.java

```
                      public class AddEntry extends Fragment implements
                   View.OnClickListener  {

               EditText DescriptionET,CalorieET;


              ImageButton savebtn;

           String description , calorieAmt;
             CalorieDatabase calorieDB;
             public AddEntry() {
             // Required empty public constructor
             }





               @Override
      public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                 // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add_entry, container, false);
               }


           @Override
      public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

      DescriptionET= (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.foodEditText);
       CalorieET=(EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.caloriesEditText);



           }

               @Override
                 public void onClick(View v) {
                     switch (v.getId()) {


                      case R.id.SaveBtn:

                      description = DescriptionET.getText().toString();
                      calorieAmt=CalorieET.getText().toString();





                         break;


                     case R.id.CancelBtn:


                          break;
                      }
                      }



                @Override
          public void onDestroy() {
                super.onDestroy();

            }

             @Override
          public void onDetach() {
                super.onDetach();
              }

                   }
```

Comment: You have a trailing comma on your create statement

Comment: your errror is here: DATABASE_CREATE_SQL, check that...

Comment: hi you have to remove semicolon from create statements ");"  and comma , from last item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "CalorieDb.db";

And then call below method in oncreat()

```
public void checkDB() {
    try {

        //android default database location is : /data/data/youapppackagename/databases/
        String packageName = this.getPackageName();
        String destPath = "/data/data/" + packageName + "/databases";
        String fullPath = "/data/data/" + packageName + "/databases/"
                + DATABASE_NAME;

        //this database folder location
        File f = new File(destPath);

        //this database file location
        File obj = new File(fullPath);

        //check if databases folder exists or not. if not create it
        if (!f.exists()) {
            f.mkdirs();
            f.createNewFile();
        }

        //check database file exists or not, if not copy database from assets
        if (!obj.exists()) {
            this.CopyDB(fullPath);
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
}
```

Unintall app and clean and rebuild project then I think solve your problem.

Comment: Now I'm not sure if I'm adding the information correctly to the database using the Entry Add Fragment  in order to display info on the listview.

Comment: you can use Gson for add value in table and retrive.

Comment: Well I have another problem , for some reason when I click the image button on my fragment home the app crashes :/  When the image button should go to to the add entry fragment

Answer (score 0):

Try Replaceing this, Removing the last **Comma(,)** from the statement

```
 private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_SQL =
              "create table " + DATABASE_TABLE
                + " (" + KEY_ROWID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
                + KEY_NAME + " text not null, "
                + KEY_CalorieValue + " integer not null "
                + ");";
```

Comment: Now I'm not sure if I'm adding the information correctly to the database using the Entry Add Fragment in order to display info on the listview

Answer (score 0):

Remove `,` from last field

```
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_SQL =
              "create table " + DATABASE_TABLE
                + " (" + KEY_ROWID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
                + KEY_NAME + " text not null, "
                + KEY_CalorieValue + " integer not null "
                + ");";
```

Answer (score -2):

```
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_SQL =
          " create table " + DATABASE_TABLE
            + " ( " + KEY_ROWID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
            + KEY_NAME + " text not null, "
            + KEY_CalorieValue + " integer not null, "
            + " ); ";
```

Add space " ) "

Comment: Now I'm not sure if I'm adding the information correctly to the database using the Entry Add Fragment in order to display info on the listview